# Add a custom view following generated text in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I have text being generated, imagine how ChatGPT generates text in batches. I'd like to have a custom view (like a cursor/caret) that follows that text. I don't mind using `UILabel`, `UITextField`, `UITextView` or anything else.

I've tried using a `UITextView` and the following code

```
override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
    let originalRect = super.caretRect(for: position)
    return CGRect(x: originalRect.origin.x, y: -3, width: 18, height: 36)
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    let caretRect = self.caretRect(for: self.selectedTextRange?.end ?? self.endOfDocument)
    customCursorImage?.draw(in: caretRect)
}
```

but it doesn't work that smoothly and I can't figure out how to hide the system cursor.

I've thought about find the `CGPoint` of the end of text and drawing the image there, but I can't find any API to do that.

Looking for any and all ideas.

Comment: Very difficult to offer help with only those code snippets. We need to see what you're doing to "generate text." Review [mre].

Comment: @DonMag this is a "how to" question, and how-to questions don't need code. The fact that the asker provided some of their attempts shows research effort from their part, which is always a good thing.

Comment: @Cristik - I still say it's tough to help without a complete example showing what the OP has done so far and demonstrating what's "not working." Or, at least it's **much easier to help** with a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

We can use text view's `selectionRects(for:)` to find the position of the end of the current text.

Here is a quick example...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let sampleStr: String = "UILabel: \n\nA label can contain an arbitrary amount of text, but UILabel may shrink, wrap, or truncate the text, depending on the size of the bounding rectangle and properties you set. You can control the font, text color, alignment, highlighting, and shadowing of the text in the label."
    
    let theTextView = UITextView()
    
    let fakeCaretView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // text view properties
        theTextView.isEditable = false
        theTextView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)
        
        theTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(theTextView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            theTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0),
        ])
        
        // let's add a button
        let b1 = UIButton()
        b1.setTitle("Do It", for: [])
        b1.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        b1.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        b1.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        
        b1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(b1)
        
        // put the button below the text view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            b1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            b1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            b1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
        ])
        
        // actions for button
        b1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doIt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        // a "caret / vertical line" view
        let lh: CGFloat = theTextView.font?.lineHeight ?? 8.0
        
        fakeCaretView.frame = .init(origin: theTextView.frame.origin, size: .init(width: 4.0, height: lh))
        fakeCaretView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(fakeCaretView)
    }
    
    @objc func doIt(_ sender: Any?) {
        var activeStrs = sampleStr.components(separatedBy: " ")
        
        // set the text view's text to the first word from the string
        var curStr: String = activeStrs.removeFirst()
        self.theTextView.text = curStr
        
        // get the "end position" and move the fakeCaretView into place
        if let p = self.findPos() {
            self.fakeCaretView.frame.origin = .init(x: self.theTextView.frame.origin.x + p.x,
                                            y: self.theTextView.frame.origin.y + p.y)
        }
        
        // repeating timer to add words one-by-one to the text view
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.25, repeats: true, block: { t in
            if activeStrs.isEmpty {
                t.invalidate()
            } else {
                // get the next word
                let s = activeStrs.removeFirst()
                // append it to the string
                curStr += " " + s
                self.theTextView.text = curStr
                // get the "end position" and move the fakeCaretView into place
                if let p = self.findPos() {
                    self.fakeCaretView.frame.origin = .init(x: self.theTextView.frame.origin.x + p.x,
                                                    y: self.theTextView.frame.origin.y + p.y)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    func findPos() -> CGPoint? {
        
        // get textRange for entire textView string
        guard let r = theTextView.textRange(from: theTextView.beginningOfDocument, to: theTextView.endOfDocument)
        else { return nil }
        
        // get the selectionRects
        let rects = theTextView.selectionRects(for: r)
        
        // get the last one
        guard let lr = rects.last
        else { return nil }
        
        return .init(x: lr.rect.maxX, y: lr.rect.minY)
        
    }
    
}
```

Notes:

- I don't know if you want to go character-by-character, word-by-word, string-by-string or paragraph-by-paragraph ... the principal will be the same.
- You'll want to add logic to handle text that is too long to fit in the text view. Probably auto-scroll it?
- This is ***Example Code ONLY!!!*** ... it is not intended to be, and should not be considered to be, "production ready."